# Cannot install ATI proprietary driver

Tags: installation, drivers, command-line, graphics

When I try

> gladoscc@comp001:~$ sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle

(The additional drivers doesn't work, gives me errors)

I get:

```
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/pxpress/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/bin/amdcccle because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/bin/amdcccle (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amdcccle.desktop because associated file /usr/share/fglrx/amdcccle.desktop (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
```

[And a bunch more of this]

```
Setting up fglrx (2:8.881-0ubuntu4.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libaticalcl.so because associated file /usr/lib32/fglrx/libaticalcl.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libaticalrt.so because associated file /usr/lib32/fglrx/libaticalrt.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf because link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken.
```

Then

```
Loading new fglrx-8.881 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.0.0-13-generic-pae
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 3.0.0-13-generic-pae
Done.

fglrx:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.0.0-13-generic-pae/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install Completed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Setting up fglrx-amdcccle (2:8.881-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-13-generic-pae
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

This is a laptop, running ATI mobility. I'm not sure of the exact name, as ubuntu will not tell me.

I have tried installing the 'post release updates' too, both via additional drivers and command line, but they give similar errors.

Answer (score 1):

That looks ok, nothing wrong with any of those logs. The driver installed normally.

To make sure that you are running the driver, after the installation, run `sudo aticonfig --initial -f`.

If there are not errors also there reboot and you should be done.

You did not include any information about your hardware, to check if that is supported visit [this site](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware).

Comment: No supported adapters detected.. I don't see any mobility cards on the site, does that mean laptops are not supported?

Answer (score 0):

Dude try this PPA it helps me:

https://launchpad.net/~andrikos/+archive/ppa

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:andrikos/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel 
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
sudo aticonfig --init
sudo reboot
```

and all will be fine :)